# SQL syntax error - incorrect syntax near ' '

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 and have created a simple app. I've created a database called Personnel with a table called Employee. I've worked through all of my syntax errors and the code looks fine, but my form - Form1.cs throws an error when I try to insert data into the database using the form.

After I insert data into the fields - ID, Name, Position and Hourly Pay Rate, then click add, it chokes on the Position field and the error reads whatever I've typed into that field.

For instance, If I enter "Manager" into that form field, the error window reads:

Incorrect syntax near 'Manager'.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated. Here's my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Personnel
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'personnelDataSet.Employee' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.employeeTableAdapter.Fill(this.personnelDataSet.Employee);

        }

        private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(global::Personnel.Properties.Settings.Default.PersonnelConnectionString);
            try
            {
                string sql = "INSERT INTO Employee (employeeID,Name,Position,HourlyPayRate) values("+txtemployeeID.Text+",'"+txtName.Text+",'"+txtPosition.Text+",'"+txtHourlyPayRate.Text+"')";
                SqlCommand exeSQL = new SqlCommand(sql, cn);
                cn.Open();
                exeSQL.ExecuteNonQuery();

                MessageBox.Show("New record added!", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                this.employeeTableAdapter.Fill(this.personnelDataSet.Employee);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            finally
            {
                cn.Close();
            }
        }

        private void btnRef_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.employeeTableAdapter.Fill(this.personnelDataSet.Employee);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your sql syntax is missing a single quote after one of the field values; Name

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: Plus what @marc said!

Comment: Thanks to all that posted. Because of many of your suggestions, I've got things working nicely now. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Please Read the comments under your post they answered your question.

1. *Your sql syntax is missing a single quote after one of the field
   values; Name –*  `Andrew Barber`
2. *[SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should not concatenate together your SQL statements - use parametrized queries instead to avoid SQL injection –*  `marc_s`

Here is how you should adjust your code:

```
string sql = @"INSERT INTO Employee (employeeID,Name,Position,HourlyPayRate) 
              VALUES(@employeeID, @Name, @Position, @HourlyPayRate )";
SqlCommand exeSQL = new SqlCommand(sql, cn);
cn.Open();
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@employeeID", txtemployeeID.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtName.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Position", txtPosition.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HourlyPayRate", txtHourlyPayRate.Text);
exeSQL.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Read up on [SqlCommand.Parameters Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Edit:

`AddWithValue` is [not 100% safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27473403/sql-syntax-error-incorrect-syntax-near/27473595?noredirect=1#comment43381841_27473595), it is better to be explicit using `Add()` for example:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@employeeID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(txtemployeeID.Text);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtName.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Position", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtPosition.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@HourlyPayRate", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = Convert.ToDecimal(txtHourlyPayRate.Text);
```

Use the proper [SqlDbType Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqldbtype(v=vs.110).aspx) and convert the values accordingly.

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: Oh I think I read this you gave it to me before. The problem is I would have to know is columns type to give proper answers because `add()` throws exceptions

Comment: agreed - one could *guess* that `EmployeeID` is probably an `int` (or should be!), while `HourlyPayRate` would most likely be a `decimal` of sorts, and the rest can be safely assumed to be strings.... Just a guess of course, since the original post didn't make this clear....

Comment: @marc_s you have a valid point I edited my post in attempt to show this. so much more code thats why I prefer EF :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

the single code should be added before and after every respective textbox values

```
 string sql = "INSERT INTO Employee (employeeID,Name,Position,HourlyPayRate) values('"+txtemployeeID.Text+"','"+txtName.Text+"','"+txtPosition.Text+"','"+txtHourlyPayRate.Text+"')";
```

Answer (score -1):

Seems you should add escape character because values("+txtemployeeID.Text+"... expands in values(Manager,... instead of values("Manager",...